# Trying to solve over 1000 different equations as fast as possible

Tags: matlab, vectorization, equations

I have a chunk of code which uses symbolic variables to solve various different equations. Currently I'm using a loop from say 1: 1000+, so that at each point it selects the right equation (depending on various if statements), and with the right constants. Since only one equation is selected, it will naturally solve it very easily. However, since there are 1000 iterations this process will take up to 30 mins (no surprise there since its a loop). This was bearable until I had to investigate the effects of the number of iterations, which means using this code for different lengths (1 to 10,000).... resulting in a horrendously slow process.

Most loops can be vectorised. However, is there a way of solving multiple equations stored in an array very quickly? Please bear in mind these are not simultaneous equations! The one variable that needs to be determined each time, is not dependent on the other equations.

Thanks for the help in advance!

D

I've Solved it. -thanks

Comment: Did you just ask everyone to vectorize your solution without showing it?

Comment: I did not want to just put my code and expect somebody to solve it. I was hoping for some general help. Especially since it's quite a large loop, and I have been re-vectorising many parts.

Comment: Do you have to represent your equations symbolically?  For example root-finding a polynomial with `roots` would probably be faster than solving a symbolic expression.  Or a numeric solver might be faster for other kinds of equations.

Answer (score 1):

The description of the problem is rather vague. However, it sounds like the problem is [embarrassingly parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel). It should therefore be easy to use multiple cores to process several equations at the same time, speeding things up.

How you do that depends on your computing environment (about which you haven't told us anything at all).

Comment: Ideally should not have to go to that stage. I am trying to find out whether it's possible to use the solve function for a large number of equations.

Comment: @user2983967: Now that you've told us you're using MATLAB, hopefully someone will chime in with concrete suggestions.

Comment: apologies. I've just been staring at it all day.